# Check if object has method in Java?

Tags: java, android, reflection, methods

I'm not all too greatly experienced with Java, I know enough to get me through at the moment, but I'm not perfect yet, so I apologize if this is a dumb question.

I'm trying to write a class that can have any sort of object passed to it, but I need to check if the object passed has a particular method with it. How would I go about testing this?

I hope this makes sense. Cheers.

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the fast replies! I'm not too familiar with interfaces etc, so I'm not entirely sure how to use them. But, to give a better insight into what I'm doing, I'm trying to create a class that will affect the alpha of an object, e.g. `ImageView` or a `TextView` for instance. How would I create an interface for that, without listing each object individually, when all I need is to make sure that they have the method `.setAlpha()`? Does this make sense? Cheers.

Comment: This is very non-Java-ish. You'd use reflection for this. A much better approach is to require an interface.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A better idea would be to create an interface with that method and make that the parameter type.  Every object passed to your method will have to implement that interface.

It's called expressing your contract with clients.  If you *require* that method, say so.

Comment: You don't have to cast that way, since it's already of the interface type.  Just call the method you say you need.

Comment: I just said that it is typed to that interface.  You can't just pass any Object; it has to implement that interface.  It's called the Liskov Substitution principle.

Comment: That's why the contract is import.  No assuming, no guessing.

Answer (score 9):

Get the instance's class with `Object.getClass()`, then use [`Class.getMethod(String, Class...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29) and catch a `NoSuchMethodException` if the class doesn't have that method.

On the other hand, this is not a very good practice in Java. Try using interfaces instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Java reflection.

Something like `object.getClass().getMethods()` to get an array of the `Method` objects, or you can use the `getMethod()` to get an object with a particular name (you have to define the parameters).

Answer (score 2):

First, define an interface that will require all objects implementing it to implement a `setAlpha()` method:

```java
public interface AlphaChanger {
    public void setAlpha(int alpha); // concrete classes must implement this
}
```

Then, define classes that implement this interface:

```java
public class Thing implements AlphaChanger {
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) { // must be present
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Now you can require that all objects passed to your method must implement the `AlphaChanger` interface:

```java
public void yourMethod(AlphaChanger changer) {
    changer.setAlpha(10); // you know for sure the method exists
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Radu, I think this is what I need. Thankyou so much for your help, I had no idea where to start, and a while back, I *attempted* looking into interfaces, and it lead me to a lot of headaches.. this has simplified it beautifully. Thank you so much, once again.

Comment: Okay, back to my silly questions. I have tried implementing this, and I'm not entirely sure how.. I have the interface in a file `AlphaChanger.java`, then the class `Thing` in another file, and I have a method for changing the alpha, with `AlphaChanger` as the typecast. When I go to use `yourMethod([ImageView object here])` though, it throws an error saying that ImageView won't work, because it needs to be of type `AlphaChanger`. 

Basically, how do I use or implement this code? Silly question, I know, but I can't figure it out :(

Comment: @Spiritfyre, the `ImageView` class (or whatever object you're passing to that method) must implement `AlphaChanger`: `class ClassName implements AlphaChanger`.

Comment: It has. Do I need to create new versions of the `ImageView` class, and every class I want passed through it, so that they can implement `AlphaChanger`?

Comment: @Spiritfyre, well, if the class that you want passed in doesn't already implement your interface, then you can write a wrapper that does (for example, `class AlphaChangerImageView extends ImageView implements AlphaChanger { public void setAlpha(int alpha) { ... } }`). The only requirement is that whatever you pass in, must implement the interface, thus ensuring that it implements the methods defined in the interface.

Comment: If you're referring to the `ImageView` Android class, you'll see that it extends `View` which defines `setAlpha()`. If you know you'll always pass views, define `yourMethod` to take a `View` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and list the classes' methods like this (example : FooBar class):

```
Class fooBar= FooBar.class;
Method[] methods = fooBar.getDeclaredMethods();
if (methods.length == 0){
...
} else{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who say that you should use an interface(superclass) declaring the required method are right. This way we test if an object is instance of it, cast and invoke.

Fortunately, setAlpha(float a) is already defined in android.view.View class - super of both TextView and ImageView. So the simplest and fastest:

```
import android.view.View;

.......

if(object instanceof View) ((View)anObject).setAlpha(a);
```

Sometimes it happens we have java.lang.reflect.Method, and want to check if it can be invoked on some object:

```
Method m;

.....

try {

   if(m.getDeclaringClass().isInstance(anObject)) m.invoke(anObject);

} catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex){ ... }
```

The principle is the same, plus a little extra effort due to reflection using.